# Retrieve ListObject column from cell as a string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

Assume I have a ListObject and I'm iterating over its rows with a for each loop. What I want to do is to further iterate over every cell inside the row and retrieve the ListObject column of this cell **as a string**.

I know you can get the cell column with cell.column but is there a way to retrieve the ListObject column as well?

EDIT: I expect the function to return the text from the header row of the ListObject.

Comment: Please, edit your question and copy the code you use. I will show you where to adapt it. Otherwise, in which way do you like to receive an answer? An explanation in words? To imagine a piece of code, since you already have one?

Comment: @FaneDuru: I have only cell.column. I want something like cell.listColumn or alike

Comment: And is the code top secret? This is your whole code you are referencing to? You were talking about iterating **by rows**. That's why it looks strange to ask about columns header for each row, since it will be the same for all columns. If it is difficult to post a piece of code, I will pos an imagined one to see how it works...

Comment: I also added a variant returning the table header for a selected cell **inside the table**. Is it what you want/need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test the next code. It is strange to return the headers so many times your code iterates by rows, so I imagined a piece of code returning the value for each row/column and the corresponding column header:

```
Sub testTableColumnByRow_Column()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rngDBR As Range, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  Set tbl = sh.ListObjects("your Table") 'use here the real table name
  Set rngDBR = tbl.DataBodyRange
  For iRow = 1 To rngDBR.rows.count
     For iCol = 1 To tbl.Range.Columns.count
        'it returns the iteration (row, column) in dataBodyRange and corresponding column header:
        Debug.Print rngDBR(iRow, iCol).value, tbl.HeaderRowRange.cells(1, iCol).value
     Next iCol
  Next iRow
End Sub
```

If you need to determine the table column of a selected cell, **inside the table**, please try the next way:

```
Sub testSelectedCellInTable()
   Dim aC As Range
   Set aC = ActiveCell
   If Not aC.ListObject Is Nothing Then 'if it is inside a table
        Debug.Print aC.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Columns(aC.column - aC.ListObject.Range.column + 1).value
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @glades Still isn't it clear how to determine the column of a cell inside the table (`listObject`)?

Comment: The second script was what I was looking for thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Return Header (String) of an Excel Table Cell

[image]

- You could use the `StrTableCellHeader` function. It is simplified ('dirty') under the assumption that you're not interested in why it may have failed i.e. returned an empty string.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function StrTableCellHeader(ByVal Cell As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
    StrTableCellHeader = CStr(Cell.EntireColumn _
        .Rows(Cell.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row).Value)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error trapping
End Function

Sub StrTableCellHeaderTEST()
    Dim Cell As Range: Set Cell = Range("B5")
    Debug.Print StrTableCellHeader(Cell)
    ' or just e.g.:
    Debug.Print StrTableCellHeader(Range("G3"))
    ' Results:
    ' Col2
    ' Col7
End Sub

Sub StrTableCellHeaderTESTErrors()
    ' The following 'Debug.Print' lines return an empty string,
    ' the default value of 'StrTableCellHeader' since an error occurred
    ' in the function.
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    ' The cell is 'Nothing' (e.g. forgotten to create a reference)
    ' ('.EntireRow' failed).
    Debug.Print StrTableCellHeader(Cell)
    ' Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
    
    ' The cell is not in an Excel table ('.ListObject' failed).
    Set Cell = Range("L10")
    Debug.Print StrTableCellHeader(Cell)
    ' Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
    
    ' 'Cell' is not a single cell
    ' ('CStr' failed because '.Value' is an array, not a simple data type).
    Set Cell = Range("A1:B2")
    Debug.Print StrTableCellHeader(Cell)
    ' Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

End Sub
```